# SSL Handshake not working on Linux but works on OS X

Tags: jvm, ubuntu-14.04, osx-yosemite, keystore, quickfixj

I'm troubleshooting an application that uses QuickFIX/J and is written in Groovy 2.4.5, built with Gradle 2.10. This FIX server also provides and API via Spring-boot 1.2.6.

While the application can connect to a test peer acceptor via SSL connection when *run from OS X*, it doesn't work when *run from Ubuntu 14.04*.

Linux event log:

> [timestamp]: Disconnecting: Socket exception (/[ip:port]): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.

I've tried checking the certificates with `keytool` but couldn't find a problem with the certificates. I've also checked that the paths to files match case, ruling out the case insensitive nature of OSX's filesystem.

The certificate is generated and signed by the company running the acceptor. How can I further troubleshoot this *handshake failure* on Ubuntu?

---

### Update

After implementing more logging for QuickFIX/J, I get extra information. All the google searches I tried didn't provide a good explanation of what the error means:

> [timestamp] [NioProcessor-3] DEBUG o.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Unexpected exception from SSLEngine.closeInbound().
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?

Comment: Please, if you are going to down vote the question, at least leave a comment as to why so I can improve it. This is a tricky question to ask. Down voting _only_ doesn't help at all.

Comment: I would try to enable logging first. I do that in my `logback.xml` file as follows: `<logger name="quickfix" level="DEBUG"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>` (The only important thing is that it's useful to enable DEBUG level for `quickfix` namespace) That should give you much more information than you have in event log file.

Comment: Please note that the `mina.filter` exception is marked as `DEBUG` message (from your update). It's hard to guess the problem, the whole log would be much more useful and somebody may spot the problem then. I received once the same error. However, in my case, it sufficed to wait for the connection to reconnect (I got the exception from your update, not the one in your event log).

Comment: I agree that if someone with more experience could see the full logs or get a reproducible build, it would help immensely. Unfortunately, I don't have permission to share the source code. On my case on every FIX Logon attempt, I get a `SSL Handshake failure` right away, the only thing in the logs is the messages I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, it turned out to be an issue with the version of Apache Mina that the QuickFIX/J library was using. We moved to using Stunnel, so I don't know whether this bug has been fixed or not.